# Declare/Undeclare Record - which Permission is needed 1. 'Manage Lists' or 2. 'Edit Items'?

Tags: 2013, permissions, records-management

Which permission is required to Declare or Undeclare a Record?  I am using In-Place Records Management.

Is the *Edit Items* or *Manage Lists* permissions needed?

OK, here are the details...Here is where the Site Collection Record Declaration Settings are configured:
[image: Site Collection Record Declaration Settings]

Yes, I realise that in this picture it says All List *Contributors* and *Administrators*.  Yet it seems the Contributors group can not Declare/Undeclare a Record, that's what [this MS link](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Configuring-in-place-records-management-7707a878-780c-4be6-9cb0-9718ecde050a) appears to say.

Yet I'm left feeling unclear, I don't know if it is because of my mid-afternoon mental dip (could be!).  MS say there are two different Permissions - it depends on whether **All list contributors and administrators** or **Only list administrators** is selected!

[image: 'Declaration Roles' - Contributor / Administator]

Here's another [MS link on Sharepoint 2013 Permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc721640.aspx) - note the distinction between the Contribute and Edit Permission Level, *Edit Items* and  *Manage Lists* permissions....

[image: Permissions]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This post](https://www.sharepointer.net/single-post/2017/05/29/How-to-Undeclare-a-Record-to-a-file-in-Document-Library-) goes some way to answering my question - it all depends on how it is configured at the Site Collection level>Record Declaration Settings.

[image: Declaration Roles]

My site collection uses the 'All list contributors and administrators' option at the site collection level.  So, unless there is an over-ride at the document library level, that means that normally 'contributors' would be able to undeclared records.  Contributors have the "edit items" permissions, so in my case this would be sufficient to undeclared a record.

As you see in the Site Permissions>Permission Levels menu - when I select the OOTB standard Contribute permission and examine which permissions this PERMISSION LEVEL is comprised of - it has the Edit Items permission.  This is enough to undeclared a record *with the configuration I have selected on the Site Collection*.

[image: Contribute]

So, it seems I was just having a 'mid-afternoon brain black-out' after all...